# Creating a Grand Central Dispatch queue for a specific singleton

Tags: cocoa, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singleton that I use for creating an application wide report. As data is passed to the singleton by the application the singleton then formats the data for use in the report. I use Grand Central Dispatch so that the report creation is not on the main thread.

My question is, would it be bad practise to create a Grand Central Dispatch queue when the singleton is initialised that is then only used by the singleton. I'd like a single thread to be associated with the singleton because if I don't some parts of the report are prone to get out of sync breaking the formatting of the report. If this is bad practise then what other pattern would be suitable for this problem but giving me quick and easy to use code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the right one. Serial dispatch queues are meant for synchronizing access to a particular resource. They process requests FIFO which makes them suitable for your requirement. I don't think the `singleton` part figures as much here.

Comment: The thing that doesn't feel right is that I'm proposing to create a GCD queue that is kept with the singleton once it is instantiated and then does nothing else. This is just to have a ready reference to the queue from the singleton rather than having to pass references around. What feels odd about this is having a GCD queue sat around doing nothing for a while if the singleton is not being used. Is this approach sensible or is there a better approach?

Comment: What's wrong with a queue sitting around? Dispatch queues are light weight objects and considering user created queues don't have threads attached to them, it shouldn't be much of a concern. I see these queues as routers to the global queues which are responsible for dealing with the management of threads. I think using GCD is an apt approach for what you're doing. This is just my bit though.